# Spring bean scope as the class of the bean its autowired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scope, javabeans

I have spring bean called `Executor` I need this executor to be Injected in two classes one is session scoped and the other is singleton, So I use `@Autowired` annotation to inject it in both, it works very fine, But for the session bean the executor is only one for all sessions, and I understand this is how it should work.

How can I make the executor take the scope of the bean its injected into ? now all I could do is use two different classes for each.

And I cant realy understand the effect of setting the attribute `scoped-proxy` in 
`<context-component-scan />` to `targetClass`.

**EDIT**

Here is my try out for prototype scope:

suppose this is my session soped bean

```
    @Component
    @Scope("session")
    public class WebExecutor(){

       @Autowired
       private ExecutorService executor;

       @Async
       public void startCalc(){
          executor.start("now");
       }

   }
```

And this is my ExecutorService class

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ExecutorService{

    private int progress;

    public void start(String when){
       //do some stuff and increment the progress
    }

    //getter and setter for progress
}
```

I also have another component with default singleton scope which autowires the executor as well, so the executor can't be session scoped.

So now I have one class needed to have the scope of the bean it is being autowired in, So I tried the prototype scope.

How this should work in the Web versions is like this

1. You click a link that begins the execution which calls the method start of the `WebExecutor`
2. Then I get the progress from the ExecutorService using the WebParser and pass it back to the user to report the progress.

This was working great before prototype but the ExecutorService was one for all sessions,

so the I used prototype but now the progress is always 0, and when I debugged the Executor I found that it was incrementing but apprentally the WebExecutor could not see the increment.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `prototype` scope. Then it will inject new instance of `Executor` when the Bean is constructed. So `Executor` starts its lifecycle when the bean is created.

`scoped-proxy=target-class` creates `CGLIB` wrapper around your bean. So other beans holds reference only to this wrapper, and the right bean with right scope is dynamically injected into this wrapper.

i.e. you don't hold very old expired `request scoped` bean in your `session scoped` bean, probably injected when the session was created . Instead new bean for current request is injected every time new request is created. This way you can access beans whith shorter life from beans with longer life i.e. your `request scoped` bean from your `session scoped` bean.

Comment: Great answer will test now and give the feedback thanks Ondrej

Comment: I tired that, but I can't get access to members of the executor in the session scoped bean after instantiating it. what i do is request something call the executor Async method and then get values from it after execution, but its not working with prototype

Comment: You call it from different `session scoped` beans? If so then it probably should have `session scope`. How long do you want your Async call with it's results to be available? One session? You shold not access your `session scoped` beans from `singletons`. You should do it vice-versa - access your `singletons` from `session beans`.

Comment: that is what I am doing exactly, but the data is not availble in the session bean, though when I debug the executor data is supposed to be available, and yes I want it to be available for one session and its the results just some value that changes while it works, and I save it as local variable to executor but then when in the Session Soped bean it is null

Comment: Are you sure that you are accessing `Executor` from the same `Session`? If you want to share your `Executor` among different sessions, you should probably make it `application scoped`.

Comment: yes I am actuly pretty sure I am same session same browser, and All I want is to use it in the other bean, without having to create a session scoped bean for the session.

Comment: So `Executor` is not session scoped? Than you could probably pass it as a parameter between those two beans... Now I don't understand. I'm not sure which bean has what scope. Please update and clarify your question.